# SQL Server Geography: How to determine distance from start of line?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Given a line which could have hundreds of vertices (a very squiggly line) with a known digitized direction, how would one go about determining, from any point along the line (not necessarily a vertice), how far that point is from the START of the line? I've been spending lots of time looking at ST_Distance functions, but can't figure out how to apply them to follow the line to determine the line distance from any point on the line.

Using SQL Server 2012 and Geography Storage format, thanks!

Comment: Add the lengths of each segment from Point A to Point B. The shorter your segments are, the more segments you will need, and the more accurate your measurement will be. Calculus is the process of taking those small segments down to infinitesimal size.

Comment: Not familiar with your data format, but if it's something akin to `PointA, PointB, Distance` or worse, but still doable `PointALat, PointALong, PointBLat, PointBLong` that makes up a vertices, and a line would be multiple records of vertices, then you could use a Recursive CTE to determine distance where you start at whatever point, then recursively work your way back to the start adding to the distance as you go. See here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=sql.105%29.aspx